# Smoother CSS transitions on element

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, timing

```js
const dot = document.querySelector( `.dot` ).style;

function getRandomInteger( min,max ) {
  min = Math.ceil( min );
  max = Math.floor( max );
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;
}

// use randomInteger for x and y values 
// for transform: translate( x%,y% )
// range here will be from negative integer 
// to positive integer. The CSS unit is a %
function move( element,range ) { 
  element.transform = 
    `
      translate( 
        ${ getRandomInteger( -range,range ) }%,
        ${ getRandomInteger( -range,range ) }%
      )
    ` 
}

//range here is 250 negative ad positive percent
setInterval( function() { move( dot,250 ) },500 );
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.dot {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.5 );
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<hr class='dot'>
```

*This code above moves a dot to a random position on the page.*

It works as expected except for the transitions from one location to another.
The *goal* being a smoother transition in between each movement.

The idea initially was to create a floating or hovering effect with subtle movements similar to an object gently floating on the surface of water.

We used `transition-timing-function: ease-in-out` on the last CSS line as an attempt to lessen the abruptness of the direction changes above. Yet altering the timing function to any value doesn't seem to help very much. Including custom `cubic-bezier` values.

**How can we get the animation to change directions less abruptly and be a smoother overall motion?**

Comment: It's probably because your transition duration is 2 seconds but your interval is every 500 ms so the transition is never getting the opportunity to finish and ease at the end of it, so it's cut off which is why it looks jerky.

Comment: @StevenB. I first tried syncing the `setInterval()` function and `transition` property to the same duration - it looks even more jumpy: https://jsfiddle.net/a3s2f87L/. Here they are both set to an equal 2 seconds in the fiddle.

Comment: You could use `transition-timing-function: linear` which would get rid of the acceleration changes between positions, but you would still have to deal with aggressive direction changes which may not look natural. Maybe you can bake in some math to get a "next random position" within an allowed angle variance to smooth it out.

Comment: @leuquim yeah. `transition-timing-function: linear` just seems to slightly change where the aggressive direction changes happen. I guess it's slightly more uniform but not in the way you'd want: https://jsfiddle.net/sLtzc40x/. I think you might be on to something with some type of tweening solution that interpolates between positions better. I've just got no idea where to start on something like that.

Comment: @devsandbox you changed the wrong parameter.  [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/p1hqsrxa/)

Comment: @StevenB. Thanks. Yeah in the JSfiddle it looks like I was in error which was making it look extra jumpy like that: Even still on the JS fiddle you provided we have this “move then stop” effect on the dot when the goal is to have one continuous smooth  motion. The accepted answer basically accomplishes this by using curves but these are predetermined paths created by an algorithm. I suspect I can use JavaScript to randomize these curves somehow though - That would be the true desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list with keyframes by javascript and creates a new animation based on the list. In this way you will avoid setInterval and the browser will animate your element by himself.

If you want even more smoother movement you should use less random values and provide keyframe list with smother positions.

```js
function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const range = 200;
const steps = 50;

const keyframes = Array.apply(null, Array(50)).map(() => {
  return {
    transform: `translate(${getRandomInteger(-range, range)}%, ${getRandomInteger(-range, range)}%)`
  };
});

document.querySelector('.dot').animate(keyframes, {
  duration: steps * 500, // 0.5 sec for keyframe
  direction: 'alternate',
  fill: 'both',
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.dot {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<hr class='dot'>
```

If you would like to achieve really smooth movement you should remove randomize and use some mathematical function to define path. Here is example based on Lissajous curve but you can use any other curves.

```js
function getLissajousCurve(radius, steps, a, b, d, A, B) {
  const result = [];
  for (let t = 0; t <= 2 * Math.PI; t += Math.PI / steps) {
    const x = radius * A * Math.sin(a * t + d);
    const y = radius * B * Math.sin(b * t);
    result.push([x, y]);
  }
  return result;
}

const steps = 50;

const curve = getLissajousCurve(200, steps, 4, 5, 0, 1, 1);

const keyframes = curve.map(([x, y]) => {
  return {
    transform: `translate(${x}%, ${y}%)`
  };
});

document.querySelector('.dot').animate(keyframes, {
  duration: steps * 500, // 0.5 sec for keyframe
  direction: 'alternate',
  fill: 'both',
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.dot {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<hr class='dot'>
```

Comment: The direction changes here still look dramatic like in the initial question. Is there a way we can smooth this out even more?

Comment: I've updated the answer with Lissajous curve example

Comment: This is definitely a step up! Thank you. Do you know of a way to draw this curve randomly? I don't want the path to be predictable but the movement is definitely far smoother

Comment: And this seems to work for what I need it for. So nevermind on randomizing it, it gives the appearance of random with a complex enough curve. Thanks again ^^

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if randomizing is possible but you can use more difficult curves instead of Lissajous. And you can change initial parameters for Lissajous curve as well.

Comment: Using `SVG` I was able to generate random curves: https://codepen.io/dev-sbx/pen/zYwdLGR